# Regex for search expression js/react

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get a regex expression that will filter an array by their title. I'm using this regex:

```
  const pattern = new RegExp('\\b' + keyword.replace(/[\W_]+/g,""), 'i')
```

Where `keyword` is a variable
But if there are spaces, nothing will be returned.
For example,

```
const books = [
 {
 title: 'Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone',
 author: 'J.K. Rowling'
 },
 {
 title: 'A Game of Thrones',
  author: 'George R.R. Martin',
}
]
```

Basically, i want to have a input that will filter through this array by title, author etc

Comment: can you provide an example of your data

Comment: Not 100% what your trying to do here but you could put an optional whitespace character like so, ```\s*``` between all other characters. Then it will find with or without spaces. You might find you only need them in certain places but without more detail it's hard to comment.

Comment: I've just edited my question

Answer (score 0):

This function filters an object array such that it only keeps an object if the search term appears in at least one of its string type fields:

```
function filterIfAnyFieldContains(objects, searchTerm) {
    return objects.filter(object => {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
            if (value.contains && value.contains(searchTerm)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

You could make use of such a function for your use case as:

```
const matches = filterIfAnyFieldContains(books, "Harry Potter");
```